# Converting many .dxf files to one file geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, convert, file-geodatabase, dxf

I am using ArcView and ArcCatalog 9.2 with the Data Interoperability extension and I have 159 .dxf files that are comprised of 6 files; a dessin DAO, an annotation DAO, a multipatch DAO; a point DAO, a polygon DAO, and a polyline DAO.

It's all in French and I don't know the english words for some of the tools. So I apologize for any unclarity.

They create a parcel layer with some building foot prints along with other features. Using a tool (Eclater un DAO; translation: Explode a DAO) in ArcCatalog that converts DAO to GDB works, but I will have to do it 159 times getting 159 different GDB when all I want is for them to be together.

Will I need to combine the 159 .dxf files into one first? If so, how do I do that without CAD?

Answer (score 4):

Since you have the Data Interoperability extension, you can create a ETL tool to load all the dxf's into a gdb (or another format of your choice), just check the help section of Data Interop. Might find something helpful read also here-  http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/datainteroperability

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to ArcInfo you could try Import from CAD:

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=import_from_cad_%28conversion%29

Comment: Agree.  Use the tool in batch mode (right click the tool and select Batch).  However, you may not have as much control over the import processe as you would with the Interop extension.  If you simply need to import them into a GDB use the Import From Cad tool.  If you need to do a few manipulations to the data before importing, use Data Interop.